# cannot resolve symbol 'REQUEST_CODE_READ_CONTACTS

Tags: android

I'm trying to request permission to access the ringer using this:

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS },
                REQUEST_CODE_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
```

What I don't understand is that the code `REQUEST_CODE_READ_CONTACTS`is showing up with the error "cannot resolve symbol 'REQUEST_CODE_READ_CONTACTS'.

Answer (score 0):

The value is a request code that you have to define yourself.

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_READ_CONTACTS = 99; // Can be any value >= 0
```

You can use it to determine which permission request the user has responded to in the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback by checking for the matching value.

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_READ_CONTACTS:
            // Do your thing
            break;
        case ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the code above from answer in this [topic](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimp87guPrUAhWjIJoKHa48ACEQFggwMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F39151453%2Fin-android-7-api-level-24-my-app-is-not-allowed-to-mute-phone-set-ringer-mode&usg=AFQjCNGjD68YQIS4gTmf13Ob_3DSmWAc9Q) 
then just initialize it with `1` and add this method in your code

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){

    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CODE_READ_CONTACTS:
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                READ_CONTACTS_GRANTED = true;
            }
    }
    if(READ_CONTACTS_GRANTED){
        loadContacts();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Allow permission in settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```